# Is it possible to get the global settings for Ajax requests in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've called $.ajaxSetup() to set some parameters.

Later I wanna get a particular setting's value (say timeout).

Is it possible to get that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do the following

```
$.ajaxSetup()['timeout']
```

AjaxSetup returns an object, from which you can query any property, (for example timeout or cache).